# Generating a function

Tags: r

I am very new to R and would like to know how a function is created.

Say if I have:

```
> colourName
 [1] "red" "green" "blue" "yellow" "white" "black"

 #Which the following colours equal something like this:
 #red = 1
 #green = 2
 #blue = 3 
 #yellow = 4
 #white = 5
 #black = 6
```

How can I create a function called `myColour()` where the result is returned as a numeric vector?

So if I type the following below, I should get:

```
> myColour("yellow")
[1] 4
```

Please help..

My Code (but its wrong!)

```
colourName<-c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white", "black")
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

myFunction <- function(colour){
colourName = data
return(colour)
}
myFunction("red")
```

Is there a possible way I can create it as a function?

Comment: Can you share what have you tried until now?

Comment: Sorry, since it was my first time, I didn't know. I have loaded my Code above but its incorrect..

Comment: @Diego Jimeno I did my research and I believe I have the rights to ask questions. It might be easy for you but I have only used R for like 3 days..

Comment: +1 for input data / what you would like to get / what you have tried. Everyone starts somewhere. Welcome to SO :-)

Answer (score 6):

You could lookup your colour(s) in a named vector, which you can do efficiently like so...

```
x <- setNames( seq_along( colourName ) , colourName )
#red  green   blue yellow  white  black 
#  1      2      3      4      5      6 

x[ 'red' ]
#red
#  1
```

Using a function here doesn't seem like a great thing to do, but if you wanted, you could have a simple lookup function like this, that takes a vector of colours and the lookup value (but you may as well just use `which`!!)...

```
myFunction <- function( colours , x){
  y <- which( colours %in% x )
  if( length(y) == 0L )
    y <- "Colour not found"
  return( y )
}

myFunction( colourName , "red")
[1] 1

#  Using R's inbuilt colour names
myFunction( colours() , "purple")
[1] 547
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's why your code is wrong, and what it does:

```
colourName<-c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white", "black")
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

that sets two variables as vectors with those values.

```
myFunction <- function(colour){
```

that starts defining a new function with one parameter, `colour`.

```
colourName = data
```

that creates another new variable called `colourName`, (the single = sign is the same as the <- sign) and gives it the value of `data`. This `colourName` variable is only visible inside the function. So now you have a `colourName` variable in the function whose value is `c(1,2,3,4,5,6)` since its a copy of `data` from outside the function.

```
return(colour)
}
```

this returns the value of `colour` as the result of the function. Since this is the same as the parameter in `myFunction <- function(colour){` and you've not changed the `colour` variable, you'll just get back what you put in!

```
myFunction("red")
```

This calls the function, setting the value of the argument `colour` to `"red"`. Now go though the function code, and you should see that it will then print `[1] "red"` - a vector identical to the input.

I know this doesn't totally answer your question of how to get the number for the colour you want, but you've clearly not understood a lot of the basics of programming so I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 this is what the answer should have been. A thorough and helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your difficulty here is that you don't need a function, rather you need a named vector

You can build up a vector for your example as follows.  There may be faster ways to do this, but I hope that this way is clear:

```
colourName=c("red","green","blue","yellow","white","black")
# Initialise a vector of numbers
colours=1:length(colourName)
# Name the vector elements according to the number-name relationship you're after
names(colours)=colourName
# See what the vector looks like
colours
# Try it out
colours["yellow"]
colours[["yellow"]]
```

UPDATE: Vectorised to give the same level of efficiency as the answers from @SimonO101.  Note that this solution (and the second solution from @SimonO101) do not require you to define a function.

Comment: How does this add anything beyond @SimonO101's answer?

Comment: You could cleanup a little with `setNames(seq_along(colourName), colourName)`.

Comment: @hadley that is *precisely* what I have in my answer.

Comment: @SimonO101 yes, I only saw that in your answer after I posted that. In my defence, it is buried at the bottom of your answer when it should be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
somevector <- c("red","blue","green")
datavector <- c(1,2,3)
mycolour <- function(whichcolour)
{
   grep(x = somevector, pattern = whichcolour)
}
```

Output -

```
> datavector[mycolour("green")]
[1] 3
```